# how to stack images when replace text to images

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

i am newbie in app script, i want to replace tagged text on 1 cell in table, with 2 image at once

i use replace text to imange using code from [Github](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/f84831455dea5c394e48caaee0058b26)

then my template goes like [this](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1jrgGnmIJNbsBuh1ayCiJYwRfQ3jDxFmyE6LuTW0HHis/edit?usp=sharing)

then I use this code to change the default text tag according to the number of uploaded images

```
function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {
  var replaceTextToImage = function(body, searchText, image, width) {
    var next = body.findText(searchText);
    if (!next) return;
    var r = next.getElement();
    //var r = next.getText();
    r.asText().setText("");
    var img = r.getParent().asParagraph().insertInlineImage(0, image);
    if (width && typeof width == "number") {
      var w = img.getWidth();
      var h = img.getHeight();
      img.setWidth(width);
      img.setHeight(width * h / w);
    }
    return next;
  };


  var foto_kegiatan_1 = e.namedValues["Foto kegiatan Pertama"][0].split(',');

  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId()); 
  var body = doc.getBody(); 

  switch(foto_kegiatan_1.length.toString()){
  case '1' :
    body.replaceText('<<Foto kegiatan Pertama>>', '<<Foto kegiatan Pertama0>>'); 
    break;
  case '2' :
    body.replaceText('<<Foto kegiatan Pertama>>', `<<Foto kegiatan Pertama0>> \n<<Foto kegiatan Pertama1>>`); 
    break;
  case '3' :
    body.replaceText('<<Foto kegiatan Pertama>>', `<<Foto kegiatan Pertama0>> \n<<Foto kegiatan Pertama1>> \n<<Foto kegiatan Pertama2>>`); 
    break;
  case '4' :
    body.replaceText('<<Foto kegiatan Pertama>>', `<<Foto kegiatan Pertama0>> \n<<Foto kegiatan Pertama1>> \n<<Foto kegiatan Pertama2>> \n<<Foto kegiatan Pertama3>>`); 
    break;
  case '5' :
    body.replaceText('<<Foto kegiatan Pertama>>', `<<Foto kegiatan Pertama0>> \n<<Foto kegiatan Pertama1>> \n<<Foto kegiatan Pertama2>> \n<<Foto kegiatan Pertama3>> \n<<Foto kegiatan Pertama4>>`); 
   break;
 default:
    body.replaceText('<<Foto kegiatan Pertama>>', " "); 
    break;
  }

  for (var counter = 0; counter < Number(foto_kegiatan_1.length); counter = counter + 1) {
    Logger.log(foto_kegiatan_1)
    Logger.log(foto_kegiatan_1[counter])
    Logger.log(`<<Foto kegiatan Pertama${counter}>>`)
 
    try{
     var link1 = DriveApp.getFileById(foto_kegiatan_1[counter].split("https://drive.google.com/open?id=")[1]).getBlob();
     replaceTextToImage(body,`<<Foto kegiatan Pertama${counter}>>`, link1, 250);
    }catch(ee){
      Logger.log(ee)
    }
}
```

but when I finish uploading the form, there is always only 1 image in 1 cell, is there something I missed?

Comment: First, I deeply apologize that my sample script was not useful for your situation. About your current issue, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: wow, I didn't expect to be answered directly by the script maker that I used
thank you, the script modification worked

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, when `r.asText().setText("");` in the function `replaceTextToImage` is run, all texts of the cell is cleared. By this, only one image is put. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue. If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification? Please modify the function `replaceTextToImage` as follows.

#### From:

```
r.asText().setText("");
```

#### To:

```
r.asText().replaceText(searchText, "");
```

- By this modification, the search text is removed. I thought that by this, both images might be able to be replaced with the images.